# Changing menu button positions

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean, samsung-galaxy-tab-2-7, home-button

After my Samsung Tab 2 7.0 got upgraded to 4.1.1 the main buttons changed place. <kbd>Back</kbd> used to be to the far left, now it's the second to the right, for example. This is amazingly annoying.

When it was new I did find some way to change these things, so I could get rid of the annoying <kbd>Screenshot</kbd> button that was installed by default. But after the upgrade, the possibility to configure this seems to have disappeared.

Any ideas?

Comment: That is part of the ROM, the only thing that can be done is to download a custom ROM such as CyanogenMod..

Comment: @t0mm13b Weird, since all screenshots of JellyBean I find has the back button to the left.

Comment: Might be Samsung-specific "refinement" then?

Comment: Could very well be. Annoying that they apparently removed their own software to modify this in the update.

Answer (score 1):

With the stock ROM, you won't be able to do anything.
Consider switching to a custom ROM like cyanogenmod.
OR, if you like the stock samsung experience, you can find several stock based ROMs on XDA which gives you this feature